# CSS Background images collapses when resolution is low

Tags: html, css

When resolution lovers my background images are collapses. I tried width 100% but not worked. Here is my page and screenshot of problem.

What should I do to prevent this? a CSS2 way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following class to your div id="navigation">

```
#navigation {
  min-width: 1024px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean stack down when device width is changing,

use css @media query and set diff percentage width to the container.

Do you want to make the website responsive, a better way is to use a grid system to 
achieve it. such as bootstrap3 , jquery-mobile etc.

They wrote the media query for you by default. javascript also can trigger responsive 
but it's heavier than pure css.

Comment: sorry i misunderstand your question first. background-size option didn't do stackdown effect usually, so i recommend you understand using @media queries. just search for how to use such css rules.

Comment: By the way your website is pretty good looking. :)  @user2578106

Answer (score 0):

Because your site isn't responsive (Seriously? This is 2014!) You need to give the `body` a minimum width large enough to accommodate your content:

```
body {
    min-width: 1030px;
}
```